# What is the correct fix instead of using if ( variable != null ) to bypass the origin of issue

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

If ( variable != null ) {now do the code that depends on variable}

Followings is a fact : Such approach supresses the business logic that when was written it assumed that a non null object will be provided, now whatever that logic was meant to do is being supressed, and the cause of the issue is being swept under the carpet.

Is there any argument against this? to provide quick fix by bypassing the cause? What is a correct design so that everywhere trough code if ( variable != null ) is not sprinkled? Or Having `if ( variable != null )` every where in the code is a good programming practice?

I am looking for a design patterns or architectural way of handling this not just by using code such as if/else/catch etc.

Comment: I don't agree that if a variable is `null` there is a problem. In fact sometimes a variable can be `null` and if you want to build a robust application you should think about that which means you should check whether it is `null` or not.

Comment: If you want to fully catch the cases, why not just add an `else` block and handle the (avoided) exception there?

Comment: this question is too broad and generic and it's impossible to provide a straight answer to it.

Comment: @KeyurPATEL : No I don't want to check the case, I don't want to put a bandate on just because somewhere some code is not getting the value to pass to the method. This is an archetural issue not coding if elses.

Comment: @Pedro : So let the monkeys keep putting their if not null bandate, can you think of how to make it more specific?

Comment: @mok : I think you mistaking an application that doesn't show problems with a robust application.

Comment: Maybe I don't get your exact meaning, but I guess you are mixing up the notions of exception and being null. Please note that for example there is an operator called null coalescing that based on your claims should not exist.

Comment: I understand your goal but I don't think it fits into a Q&A format. Some thoughts: 1) source control tools (e.g., Subversion) show who's to "blame" for the line—but that's retrospective. 2) A great, old VB6 error handling library said, "**Errors are our friends; _They help us find bugs._**"—you know that already. 3) PragProg: "Find Bugs Once": Write tests around bugs before the fix, ensuring proper fixes. 4) Deliberately deciding to treat the symptom instead of the bug is a form of technical debt. Log it. Prepare to pay it later.

Comment: May I know your opinion about the `nullable type`?  If that is a bandage, then we should not introduce this, so every variable should have value assigned, isn't it?

Comment: @Alex : Nobody said anything about null, I am not sure how it is not clear from the question that if a method expects and depends an instance of something to do what it needs to do, and somewhere somehow it is being passed a null, then the fix is to make the method do nothing rather than actually call a different method that is designed for that condition. I think people are thinking too low level, rather than architectural issue here.

Comment: So that you are talking about business logic, if the logic really side stepped, should it fail in black-box testing?

Comment: @Alex : I don't know sir! That is why I asked the question :)

Comment: @Alex : from what you saying it seems that there is nothing wrong with that type of coding and it should be caught in testing, That is good information, and I couldn't care less about the code, unless there is a pattern that helps with that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's really a business reason to cater for the situation where your `variable` is `null`, then you the developer should provide an `else` block.

Concerning literature, yes there is actually a performance cost to throwing exceptions, so it's recommended you avoid your app throwing exceptions as much as possible. [You can read more about it on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229009(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: It is not about throwing exceptions, but finding and preventing where null values will be passed as parameter architecturally, and not by hand coding.

Comment: @Arjang, I'm not sure how you want to successfully separate Architecture from Implementation, practically speaking. If there's some "business logic" out there, then it's the duty of the code to be faithful to it, and the duty of the tests to validate the assumptions on the business requirements. For all we care, the code could have been outright buggy or doing something completely different from the intent. That's why tests and testers are supposed to fish out.